# yfinance's download doesn;t work is interval less than 1 day

Tags: python, yfinance

Below some simple yfinance code (in Python); the first download works fine, the second returns an empty dataframe. Why?

Any help appreciated - Michael

```
import yfinance as yf

isin = "SPX.L"

# Comfirm share exists
share = yf.Ticker(isin)
info = share.info
print(isin + " exists :: name=" + info.get('shortName'))

# Get historical data
df1 = yf.download(tickers=isin, period="1mo", interval="1d", auto_adjust=True, prepost=False)
print(df1)
df2 = yf.download(tickers=isin, period="5d", interval="1h", auto_adjust=True, prepost=False)
print(df2)
```

Comment: The second command works for me. There might be some rate limit in place for the two calls in quick succession. You could try `import time; time.sleep(5)`, for example, in between.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Alas, if I do as you suggest (or comment out the two statements related to df1) I still get an empty dataframe for df2. How the heck is it possible that this works fine for you and not for me? Note that is used to work fine for me also, but today the behaviour has changed for the worse on my machine. Any ideas?

Comment: @mkemper Maybe you can try upping the sleep delay, It can just be a slow device on your end, or the module being funky.

Comment: I am not sure, and maybe Brody is on to something with waiting longer. But just to remove another potential source of doubt: before testing this, I upgraded to the latest version I could: 0.1.63

Comment: I like the idea of going to the latest version of yfinance. I have never done this before. Is it a question of downloading and re-pipping? Thanks for the help both!

Comment: It'd be like this: `pip install --upgrade yfinance`. Best of luck.

Comment: I updated (using your pip statement - thanks), and ... the problem has evaporated! Why it used to work in the previous incarnation of yfinance and then all of a sudden no longer so will remain a mystery (I suspect the introduction of the new release had an impact on the old release). Anyhow, problem sorted so once again many thanks!

Comment: Damn! I spoke to soon. For a good while my program was working fine using the latest yfinance release, getting the latest data (using period="1d", interval="1m" for instance), and now all of a sudden I get empty dataframes again, calling exactly the same yf.download(...) statements. Grrrr. I am now totally stuck... Any thoughts?